# $f(0)=0,$ and $ f(t)=t^{2} \sin (1 / t) \text { if } t \neq 0 $ Show $f$ is differentiable at $0,$ and calculate $f^{\prime}(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

- Define $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ by setting $f(0)=0,$ and
  $$
  f(t)=t^{2} \sin (1 / t) \text { if } t \neq 0
  $$
  Show $f$ is differentiable at $0,$ and calculate $f^{\prime}(0)$.

  My attempt. $f'(t)=2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{t}\right) t-\cos \left(\frac{1}{t}\right).$

Note that $\sin(1/0)$ and $\cos(1/0)$ are undefined so how can I calculate $f'(0)$, may you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By limit definition of the derivative

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin(1/h) -0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h\sin(1/h)$$

Note that

$$0 \le |h \sin(1/h)| \le |h| |\sin(1/h)| \le |h|$$

where we used that $|sin(1/h)| \le 1$. So by Squeeze Theorem,

$$0 = \lim_{h \to 0} 0 \le \lim_{h \to 0} |h\sin(1/h)| \le \lim_{h \to 0} |h| = 0$$

So we conclude that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} h \sin(1/h) = 0 \implies f'(0) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0)=0$ and for $t\ne 0$
$$f(t)=t^{2} \sin (1 / t)$$
$$f'(0) = \lim _{t\to 0}\frac {f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=$$
$$f'(0) = \lim _{t\to 0}\frac {t^{2} \sin (1 / t)}{t}=$$

$$\lim  _{t\to 0}t \sin (1/t) =0$$